# Adding options to existing .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess code which I have put together from different sources and I am having trouble adding a couple of extra options to it.

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</Limit>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# allow things that are certainly necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/js/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/"

RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)$  index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3&quaternary=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)$  index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_%]+)$  index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)$  index.php?primary=$1
```

Firstly I would like to add the forced use of `www.` in the URL.  When I have tried to add this, the resulting URL becomes the output of the current `RewriteRule`s, containing the `GET` variables.  I believe this is because the rules work on a loop?

Another thing I would like to do is catch anything that doesnt meet the criteria of the current rules and send that to something like `index.php?primary=error`.  The way it works now is *almost* perfect for my use because if there is a malformed URL or illegal character, the site is not going to even attempt to display the page.  The site will create all URLs safely, so any bad URLs would be the result of experimenting in the address bar, but it would be nice to have an error page rather than a *page not found*.

Thanks in advance.. And sorry for the muddle-through use of `RewriteRule`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex are incorrect since hyphen can be unescaped only when it appears as first or last symbol in a character class, it needs to be escaped otherwise.

So instead of: `[a-zA-Z0-9-/_%]`
Use: `[\w%/-]`

Your complete set of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www in the URL    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# allow things that are certainly necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|images)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3&quaternary=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?primary=$1&secondary=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?primary=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That's certainly a lot tider, thank you.  Triggering one of the last 4 RewriteRules causes me to get a page not found though.. As if using a simple word for the last rule doesnt qualify as valid.

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: It only allows specific IP addresses, so I'll write them up as: http://www.domain.com/hub (doesnt work), http://www.domain.com (does work)

Comment: I had `RewriteRule .* - [L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` lol.  Fixed now, thanks.  Any help with the _www_ and _page not found_ would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks, anubhava.  I've gone ahead and marked your answer because my .htaccess is behaving **much** better now.  If it's possible though, do you mind seeing how I can overcome the `404` problem that I am having? If I do something like `domain.com/test/test/te.st`, it correctly fails to match any of the `RewriteRule`s and the broswer shows it's default 404 page because nothing exists at that address.  If I include `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php`, exactly the same thing happens. (I don't even get an apache error trying to locate the error document)